# Pattern Matching for inquire object type and MSBuild 14

Tags: c#, tfs, compilation, msbuild, continuous-integration

I'm working on just migrate code for an application on Framework 4.5 using VS2019 in my development environment.

We work using TFS for CI/CD, that server is using MSBuild14 in order to compile applications (I don't know if developer packs and versions had has installed)

So when I use in my version expresions (Pattern matching, after C# 7.0 I thing) like:

```
if (ex is HttpException httEx && httEx.ErrorCode == 404)
{
  return;
}
```

Compilation fails informing side efects error like ") expected" in different lines of code.

So, I'm guessing that the problem is because I using diferent compilation method, like MSBuild Tools for VS2019 and maybe different developers pack on compiler server.

So, how I can duplicate the environment of compilation, because is much more simple than the company make an install? Can I link MSBuild 14 local version and foce to compile using particular framework? In VS2019

Or, how can ask for server environment update in order to utilice those type of sintaxis?, Must update MSBuild? Install developer pack of framework 7+ ? all of those?

Answer (score 1):

> We work using TFS for CI/CD, that server is using MSBuild14

To support C# 7 features we need to use Msbuild15.0 version or higher. (VS2015 <=> MSBuild14.0, VS2017 <=> MSBuild15.0, VS2019 <=> MSBuild16.0)

You can download and install [Visual Studio 2019](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/) or [Build Tools for Visual Studio 2019](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/thank-you-downloading-visual-studio/?sku=BuildTools&rel=16)(Scroll down to "Tools for Visual Studio 2019" and choose "Build Tools for Visual Studio 2019") on your TFS Server.

Secondly, update your self-hosted agent on your TFS Server.

Finally, please check your agent Capabilities if there is a new version of MSbuild. [image]

Answer (score 1):

> how I can duplicate the environment of compilation, because is much more simple than the company make an install? Can I link MSBuild 14 local version and foce to compile using particular framework? In VS2019
>
> Or, how can ask for server environment update in order to utilice
> those type of sintaxis?, Must update MSBuild? Install developer pack
> of framework 7+ ? all of those?

I am afraid you **have to** update MSBuild and Install developer pack of framework 7+.

I can understand that this may be painful and troublesome, but it is inevitable in the software development process. As we know, software products are basically backward compatible but not upward compatible. Developers and decision makers are more willing to update and release new features on the new version instead of adding these new features to the old version.

So we can compile the old code in the new compiler (except those deprecated features), but we could not make the old compiler compile the code developed on the higher version. Because the new method is not integrated into the old version of the compiler, this is reason why you get the error.

Similarly, for your question, I think it is not possible to use MSBuild `14.0` to compile `C#7` in a server environment (supported in `15.0` and above). Of course, if you do not want to install full Visual Studio, you can use Visual Studio build tool instead of full Visual Studio.

Comment: My mistake explaining me, I mean, one option is force to restrict my local environment compilation in order to replicate the possible errors on compilation server detecting early when I'm using some sintaxis that will get an error in compilation ... how may I can do dis?

Comment: @rolivaresr, I am afraid that there is no such way to detect errors as early as possible, until we call those new functions on the old compiler.